# jQuery input .on() how handling event when browser change value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, webbrowser-control

I have two fields in my form, I need handle event when browser changes value of them, my fields are username and password; I've used this `$('input').on('input change',function(e){//...})`, but when I select a user name in list that popped up by my browser, value of password changes but `'input'` event of password not working in that case.

How can I handle that ?

Code:

HTML:

```
<form action="/">
  <input name="username" type="text" />
  <br />
  <input name="password" type="password" />
  <br />
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Js:

```
$('input[type="password"]').on('change keyup',function(event){
  console.log(event.type);
});
```

It's working when I'm typing in password field, but not working when browser auto complete is changing password value.

Comment: please tell us more about your codes

Comment: @AliCarikcioglu question has been updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is browser behavior, not about scripting. I think there is no easy way to go around this.

A workaround is to set up a timer to periodically check for changes in the field.

Another workaround is to set up the `onfocus` to capture the **before value** and `onblur` event to capture the **after value** and compare if the value changes.

If it's crucial to you to handle the event when the field value changes. I think you should disable browser auto complete by specifying `autocomplete="off"` on the field and optionally implement auto complete yourself.

For more information, see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag).

Answer (score 0):

It should be `$('input').on('change', function(e){//...})` as [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) says

> .on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler(eventObject) )

you can try with this also:

```
$('input[type=text], input[type=password]').on('change', function(e){//...})
```

Comment: @OMiD.. Encase you code inside `DOM Ready handler`, if the script is defined inside head element

Comment: `$('input[type=text], input[type=password]').on('change', function(e){/*...*/})` not working too, the problem is not selector I think.

Comment: try with `.on('change keyup'` instead of `.on('change'` maybe this would help for browser autocomplete

Comment: @Daniele still nothing, I did change my username value by auto compelete but browser changes my password value too, i need to handle event when password changes.